# Java How can i add an element into my array?

Tags: java, bluej

my constructor containing my array:

```
public Library(int maxNumberofTextBook)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    nextBook = 0;
    numberOfBorrowers = 0;
    numberOfChapters = 6;
    bookShelf = new Textbook[maxNumberofTextBook + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < maxNumberofTextBook; i++)
        bookShelf[i] = new Textbook("Text book number" +i, numberOfChapters);
}
```

in this method i want the array to take the parameter input and add it to the array above:

```
public void returnBook(Textbook book)
{
    //add book into array//
    numberOfBorrowers -- ; 
    bookInShelf ++ ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example, i see that you are using a a primitive `fixed-size` `array`,

```
  Textbook bookShelf []  =  new Textbook [maxNumberofTextBook];
```

To add an new Object you just assign it ( `ArrayOutOfBoundException` might be thrown)

```
public void returnBook(Textbook book)
    {
     if(bookInShelf  < maxNumberofTextBook ){ //just to avoid the exception
         bookShelf[maxNumberofTextBook - 1] = book;
         numberOfBorrowers -- ; 
         bookInShelf ++ ; 
     }

    }
```

Comment: for this assignment out lecturer told us not to use arraylists so i have been avoiding that 

also when does this input the parameter input in book

Comment: Ok and what about the book position inside the array ?

Comment: i seem to get the hang of it now, chers

lastly does
bookShelf[nextBook] = null;
set the location to null or the value to null?

Comment: bookShelf[nextBook]  = null is the Object at this position will be null, and you need to handle the check on null after if you want to print them (To avoid null pointer exception )

Answer (score 0):

This is meant as guidance, don't expect people to do your homework ...

First of all, your requirements are a bit unclear, thus the *first*, most important step is get to a clear "mental model"!

I *assume* you want a system that looks like this:

- there is known set of books titles that the library carries
- for each book: there is a distinct "shelf" where all books of that title sit
- for each book title: there is number of actual books

And now, what you have to think about:

- borrowing a book means: reduce the number of *actual* book instances on that shelf position, and increase the counter of borrowed books for that title
- returning means the opposite: increase the "number of books in shelf" counter, and reduce the "borrowed books" counter.

So, what you have to do: look carefully at your code, and ensure that you can express all these above aspects.

In other words, you need code that can express:

- "there is that book named Moby Dick"
- "Moby Dick sits on shelf 5"
- right now, 5 instances of "Moby Dick" are on the shelf
- right now, 3 instances of "Moby Dick" are "out" to borrowers